# Python Prime Number Program Bug

Tags: python

I am trying to make as a challenge a program that can perform different tasks relating to prime numbers. One of these tasks is saying wheather a number you enter is a prime number (this is option A in the menu defined as choice). The loop that isn't looping is in the section defined as nomtyre. It would really help me if you could just have a look and tell me what you think could be the  problem with it.

```
    import time

def nomtyre():
    divider = 2
    if divider == number:
        print (number," is a prime number.")
        divider = 2
        time.sleep(3)
        choice()
    else:
        if number % divider == 0:
            divider = divider + 1
            nomtyre()
        else:
            print (number," is not a prime number.")
            divider = 2
            time.sleep(3)
            choice()

def nomty():
    number = int(input("Please enter your whole number: "))

def choice():
    print ("Would you like to:")
    print ("a) Type in a number to be decided wheather it is a prime number or not.")
    print ("b) Have prime numbers calculated from 2 upwards.")
    print ("c) Exit.")
    answer = input("So what would you like to do? a/b/c: ")
    if answer == "a" or answer =="A":
        nomty()
    elif answer == "b" or answer == "B":
        nomup()
    elif answer == "c" or answer == "C":
        print ("Thank you for using Prime Number calcultor...")
        time.sleep(1.5)
    else:
        print ("Sorry, that wasn't a choice, please try again")
        time.sleep(1.5)
        choice()

print ("Welcome to Prime Number Calculator...")
time.sleep(1)
choice()
```

Comment: `nomty()` what does it do. nothing? AND `nomup()` oops not found at all. I would like to give 1 suggestion - use `PyDev` plugin in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

First, you never call nomtyre, which is why it never runs. Also, nomtyre never defines divider or number (I think you want to pass them in as parameters). Try something like this:

```
import time

def nomtyre(number, divider):
    if divider == number:
        print (number," is a prime number.")
        divider = 2
        time.sleep(3)
        choice()
    else:
        if number % divider == 0:
            divider = divider + 1
            nomtyre(number, divider)
        else:
            print (number," is not a prime number.")
            time.sleep(3)
            choice()

def nomty():
    return int(input("Please enter your whole number: "))

def choice():
    print ("Would you like to:")
    print ("a) Type in a number to be decided wheather it is a prime number or not.")
    print ("b) Have prime numbers calculated from 2 upwards.")
    print ("c) Exit.")
    answer = input("So what would you like to do? a/b/c: ")
    if answer == "a" or answer =="A":
        nomtyre(nomty(), 2) #makes the given input the number and sets the divider to 2 initially
    elif answer == "b" or answer == "B":
        nomup()
    elif answer == "c" or answer == "C":
        print ("Thank you for using Prime Number calcultor...")
        time.sleep(1.5)
    else:
        print ("Sorry, that wasn't a choice, please try again")
        time.sleep(1.5)
        choice()

print ("Welcome to Prime Number Calculator...")
time.sleep(1)
choice()
```

Comment: when ener that code though and run the run it, it comes up with this error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/Prime number Calculator.py", line 41, in <module>
    choice()
  File "C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/Prime number Calculator.py", line 28, in choice
    nomtyre(nomty(), 2) #makes the given input the number and sets the divider to 2 initially
  File "C:/Users/Josh/Desktop/Prime number Calculator.py", line 10, in nomtyre
    if number % divider == 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
>>> 
[

Comment: change nomty to this:  return int(input("Please enter your whole number: ")) (I edited my answer to fix that issue)

Answer (score 0):

`nomtyre` is never called in this code.  So any code inside it will never execute.  In order to get a function to execute, you have to call it like this.

```
nomtyre()
```